# How to connection sybaseanywhere 9.0?

Tags: vb.net, sybase

I'm trying to connection sybaseanywhere 9.0 .It's very long time for open connection.
I think my code not work.I want to know How to open connection sybaseanywhere 9?

I using Sap.Data.SQLAnywhere.v4.5.DLL on my webservice .Net Framework 4.5 and I install sybaseAnywhere 17.0 on my computer.
My server is SybaseAnywhere 9.0 . I can't update database anywhere 9.0 to 17.0.

I'm so sorry for my English.My English skill is bad. 
If you don't understand me ,please ask me.
Please help me.

This is my code

```vb
Imports Sap.Data.SQLAnywhere

Public Function SelectDataFromSybaseH(ByVal oFrom As String, ByVal oTo As String, ByVal sEmpCode As String) As DataTable
 Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
 Using con As SAConnection = New SAConnection("UserID=*****;Password=*****;ServerName=myserver;Connection Timeout=60;Host=192.168.1.5")

                Dim sCmd As String = " select * from myTable "
                Dim oCmd As SACommand = New SACommand(sCmd, con)
                Dim oAdp As SADataAdapter = New SADataAdapter(oCmd)
                oAdp.Fill(dt)


 End Using
 Return dt
End Function
```

It doesn't show error.I don't know Why.

Comment: What are the arguments passed into the function used for?

Comment: The function is get data employee attendance by employee code and return it.